# How can I run an acceptance test?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have the following `tests/acceptance/index-test.js` in an ember-cli version 0.0.22 app:

```
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';
test('index transitions', function(){
  visit('/');
});
```

When I go to `http://localhost:4200/tests` I see:

```
Died on test #1
at eval (ember-cli/tests/acceptance/index-test.js:7:5)
at requireModule (loader/loader.js:54:29)
at eval (ember-cli/tests/test-loader.js:9:7)
at Array.forEach (native)
at eval (ember-cli/tests/test-loader.js:8:8)
at requireModule (loader/loader.js:54:29)
at http://localhost:4200/tests:43:7: visit is not defined

Source: ReferenceError: visit is not defined
at Object.eval (ember-cli/tests/acceptance/index-test.js:8:7)
```

It seems I'm having trouble loading code. Placeholder files in the project would be useful. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed to call `startApp();` in the test file, like:

```
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';

test('index transitions', function(){
  startApp();
  visit('/');
  andThen(function(){
    equal(find('h3.breadcrumb').text(), 'Title');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I added [this section](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#using-ember-qunit-for-integration-tests) to the documentation for ember-cli.

Be sure to to invoke `startApp()` in `setup` of the module, like so:

```
 module('An Integration test', {
     setup: function() {
         App = startApp();
     },
     teardown: function() {
         Ember.run(App, App.destroy);
     },
 });
```

... instead of within each `test`.